# make alert call when checkbox is unchecked and button clicked

Tags: angularjs

hello i am new in angular.js and i am currently finding a code to do alert call on button click. i have tried something. i have one checkbox one button and one label. i want to keep alert on button's on click. Here is my code.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="mySwitch=true">
<p>
<button ng-disabled="mySwitch" id="demo" type="button" onclick="javascript:alert1();">Click Me!</button>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitch"/>Button
</p>
<p>
{{ mySwitch }}
</p>
</div> `
```

and here it is my jquery

```
alert1()
{
   alert('hi');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="mySwitch=true">
<p>
<button ng-disabled="mySwitch" id="demo" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = alert('hi')">Click Me!</button>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitch"/>Button
</p>
 <p>
     {{ mySwitch }}
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah we can write all in just one line also.... why to add extra line while we can do in one. Thanx dude

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), only works when you're element is not disabled

```
<button ng-disabled="mySwitch" id="demo" type="button" ng-click="someFunction();">Click Me!</button>
```

In controller

```
$scope.someFunction = function () {
 alert("demo");
}
```

If you're `ng-disbaled` comes true, it will not going to bind any event because

> Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. Most browsers will
>   propagate an event originating from the disabled element up the DOM
>   tree, so event handlers could be placed on container elements.